# Integrating with an array of upper limits without sacrificing time efficiency

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I am working on an algorithm to compute some model. Let's say

```
def model(z):
    return z ** 2
```

Now, I need to use an array of upper limits to compute an array of values for definite integrals of this function. I.e.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
upp_lim = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
res_arr = quad(model, 0, upp_lim)
```

This of course, gives the error:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

The issue here is that I need to further work on this function by using it in an MCMC model (emcee). Hence, if I use any sort of loop, the MCMC algorithm will take an extremely long time to run, even with multiprocessing.

Is there a method to have the integration function accept an array of upper limits without sacrificing this much time? The quad module is not a necessity, however it is the fastest module I have found.

Existing questions give iteration as an answer. Some pre-existing questions do not iterate over the limits, however still involve some component of iteration. This is out of my question's scope as I am wondering whether an alternative exists.

Comment: Adapting the code from that question to your question, I can use `lower_bound = 0; x_vals = [lower_bound] + sorted(upp_lim); res_arr = np.cumsum([quad(model, x_vals[i], x_vals[i + 1])[0] for i in range(len(x_vals) - 1)])` to obtain the definite integrals you want without integrating over the same range multiple times.

Comment: @NickODell As mentioned in the question description, the time efficiency of the algorithm is severely affected given the iterating component of the code suggested by your linked pre-existing question. My question, differing from pre-existing questions, is whether there is a different method/library that can prevent this lack of efficiency, given that I am performing MCMC analysis.

Comment: I don't see how you'd evaluate a definite integral at many points without some kind of loop. Is it possible to symbolically integrate your function? That may be a path to a faster approach.

Comment: @NickODell Unfortunately, I have to agree with you. The solution to this will have to be mathematical and not computational.